# Convince that zero is an even number

Tags: integers

Convince that zero is an even number

- I am not quite sure on this question can anyone help?

Comment: $0=2\cdot 0\in 2\mathbb Z$

Comment: Could those who down-voted this question explain why?

Comment: I changed the tag from "calculus" to "integers" as this question is definitely not calculus. If someone else can think of  a better tag, feel free to change it.

Comment: Numbers were last digit is zero, are even. The number Zero is neither odd nor even. See => Number Zero parity | zero http://tinyurl.com/oexhr3k . You have +1 from me for good Q.